# Necesito realizar una autenticacion en firebase con numero de celular dentro de mi app Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

estoy realizando una app en la cual manejo un lgin de facebook uno de google y deseo implementar el login con el numero de celular, esos login los tengo dentro de un provider que me maneja el usuario a nivel general de toda la app. 
Este es el codigo del Provider.

el Login de Facebok y google funcionan bien, pero el de  celular no me funciona, si alguuien puede ayudarme le agradeceria

```
enum LoginProvider{
  PHONE,
  GOOGLE,
  FACEBOOK,
}

//Aqui esta la clase del provider
class LoginState with ChangeNotifier {  

  String phoneNumber;
  String codeSms;
  String verificationId;

LoginState({this.codeSms, this.phoneNumber, this.verificationId});

  bool _loggedIn = false;
  FirebaseUser _user;
  bool isLoggenIn()=> _loggedIn ;
  FirebaseUser currentUser() => _user;

//Metodo de redireccionamiento de los Proveedores los diferentes login

void login ( BuildContext context, LoginProvider loginProvider )async{ 
    switch(loginProvider){
      case LoginProvider.GOOGLE:
         _user = await _handleSignIn();
        break;
      case LoginProvider.FACEBOOK:
       _user = await _handleFacebookSignIn();
       break;
      case LoginProvider.PHONE:
        _user = await verifyPhone(context);
        break;
    }    
    if (_user != null) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "home_page");
    } else {
      LoginPage();
    }
    _loggedIn = true;
    notifyListeners();      
    }
```

// aqui deseo implementar  la autenticacion con el numero de celular//

```
 Future<FirebaseUser> verifyPhone(BuildContext context)async{ 
  FirebaseAuth _phoneAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  _phoneAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber, 
    timeout: Duration(seconds: 60), 
    verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential credential )async{
      AuthResult result = await _phoneAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
        return user;  
    }, 
    verificationFailed: (AuthException exception){
      print(exception);
    }, 
    codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResenndingToken]){
    Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _ , __) =>ValidationNumber() 
    ));
    }, 
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: null);

}



}
```

Comment: Hay algún error en los logs al momento de usar la verificación por número de teléfono ?

Comment: No men, los otros dos Login estan funcionando bien, el problema que tengo es que no tengo idea de como implementar ese login de telefono, no he dado para llamarlo en el frente, no he dado para enviarlo  a la pantalla de verficacion del codigo, he tenido bastantes inconvenientes con ese login, llevo varios dias intentando hacerlo y no lo he logrado, si me pudieras ayudar coneso